# Remove the Marlin Boot screen

Tags: marlin

I added a custom boot screen to marlin by adding `_Bootscreen.h` to the project root folder and it works fine. The problem is that the custom screen shows quickly and disappear then the marlin boot screen is then displayed for a longer time.
I want to remove the marlin boot screen.

I dug around in the source code and found a `void lcd_bootscreen` function in the   `ultralcd_impl_HD44780.h` header. This seems to be the function that is loading the marlin's boot screen due to the comments in the code. I added `return;` to the **first line** of code in this function but the marlin's boot screen is still loading.

How can I remove the marlin boot screen. How can make my custom boot screen wait for more time?

The marlin version is 1.1.8.

Comment: Not working with marlin, but I'd better set `#undef SHOW_BOOTSCREEN` in Configure.h per [documentation](http://marlinfw.org/docs/configuration/configuration.html#firmware-info) to disable the marlin boot screen than messing with any other header.

Comment: @Tensibai `SHOW_BOOTSCREEN` is also used to control the custom bootscreen. If I do this, my custom bootscreen will not display.

Comment: I'd have to dig in the header more to see which part loads the custom boots screen and which replace it with the marlin one then. The file in dot h are headers (declarations) so modifying the function return is not very likely to help, there's probably a better approach to drive that

Comment: I know it is a header file and mentioned that in my question. There is no corresponding .cpp file for the `ultralcd_impl_HD44780.h` file. They put the code in the .h file. Check [it](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/ultralcd_impl_HD44780.h) out when you have time

Comment: It doesn't need a corresponding cpp file, just that the various headers are defined, there's various code in this header called somewhere in the code 'main' function to really do something... I feel there's something not properly overridden in your custom file, but I can just guess without it and the documentation you follow

Answer (score 4):

You can add return; command in the `ultralcd_impl_DOGM.h` file.

```
  void lcd_bootscreen() { 
    #if ENABLED(SHOW_CUSTOM_BOOTSCREEN)
      lcd_custom_bootscreen();
    #endif
    return;  // Add this line
```

Answer (score 2):

So after some search:

1. You can't (at least should not) remove the Marlin bootscreen according to this issue [`SHOW_CUSTOM_BOOTSCREEN` hides Marlin logo](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/8186), quote:

   > We wanted an additional logo - not a replacement of the Marlin logo.
2. According to the [code here](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/ultralcd_impl_DOGM.h#L282-L306) there's a constant `CUSTOM_BOOTSCREEN_TIMEOUT` taking the default value of 2500 which is 2.5 seconds but you can redefine it in your `_Boostrap.h` file.

This constant is only available for DOGM lcd screens which is chosen by the code here in [`ultralcd.cpp`](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/ultralcd.cpp#L95-L100) and without more details on your machine it's hard to tell from [`Conditionals_LCD.h`](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/Conditionals_LCD.h) which will be used.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to remove the Marlin bootscreen and still retain the custom one by commenting out the following line in `marlinui_DOGM.cpp` (`Marlin/Marlin/src/lcd/dogm/marlinui_DOGM.cpp`):

```
void MarlinUI::show_bootscreen() {
    TERN_(SHOW_CUSTOM_BOOTSCREEN, show_custom_bootscreen());
    // show_marlin_bootscreen();
  }
```

Tested and working as of Marlin 2.0.x.